# How to call a function every x seconds with updated state (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having a lot of trouble with this and i have tried various things. I want to call a function every second after i have clicked a start button and then have it paused after i click a stop button. I keep getting weird behaviour that i cant explain.
How can i do this in react without classes?

somethings i have treid:

```
      const simulation = () => {
    if (!running) {
      console.log('hit');
      return

    } else {
      // console.log(grid);
      console.log('hey');
      setTimeout(simulation, 1000)
    }
  }
```

and

```
    enter  setInterval(() => {
    let newGrid = [...grid]
    for (let i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < numCol; k++) {
        let n = 0;
      }
    }
    console.log(grid);
  }, 5000)
```

I have tried a lot more, In some cases it would update the state should i have added to it but not updated it after i reset the state.
How can i call a function to run every one second with updated values of state * Note the function that i want to run will update the state

Comment: Do you need accurate timing?

Comment: I guess not - just consistent timing

Comment: why do you need to update the state? Did you hear about hooks? and useEffect hook?

Comment: setInterval and setTimeout are not reliable for time tracking

Comment: I need to update the state because im recreating the game of life - Every 1 second i want to run a function that will change the state

Comment: @AxelAldrich I dont need too much accuracy of or consistency, Just enough that it works

Comment: Not sure if it would fit your use case, but you could just store the value when you hit the start button.  Then calculate using that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do the following:

- keep track of the current counter value along with the counter on/off state in your component state;
- employ `useEffect()` hook to be called upon turning counter on/off or incrementing that;
- within `useEffect()` body you may call the function, incrementing `count` by one (if `ticking` is truthy, hence timer is on) with delayed execution (using `setTimeout()`);
- once `count` variable is changed in the state, `useEffect()` gets called once again in a loop;
- in order to [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) the timer upon component dismantle, you should return a callback, clearing the timer from `useEffect()`

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const App = () => {
  const [ticking, setTicking] = useState(true),
        [count, setCount] = useState(0)
   
   useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => ticking && setCount(count+1), 1e3)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
   }, [count, ticking])
   
   return (
    <div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setTicking(false)}>pause</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTicking(true)}>resume</button>
    </div>
   )
}  

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting, Why are you clearing the interval every time?

Comment: @ST : `clearInterval()` is, in fact, invoked [only once](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) on component unmount

Comment: Why is the clear interval being returned? whats actually being returned and where to?

Comment: I used your answer to make my own:                                                                    
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)

  const incTimer = () => {
    setTimer(timer + 1)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(running);
    if (!running) {
      return;
    } else {
      const interval = setInterval(incTimer, 1000)
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    }

  }, [timer, running])

Comment: The returned function in a useEffect serves as a callback when component is unmounting, so that interval get cleared at the end of the component lifecycle.

Comment: Please, add at least empty array for denpendencies yo prevent it from rendering infinitely. I almost killed my Macbook with useEffect + setInterval. The most dangerous combination I've experimented. My Macbook went off within 30 seconds, with no fan acceleration, nor processor heating. I couldn't revive it even after removing battery. After 5 hours, it started again finally. Lol

Comment: This answer would be better with explanation of the code, rather than essentially "this good?"

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but maybe interesting for some people.
Look at npm package cron. In this case every 15min As easy as:

```
const [job] = useState(new cron.CronJob("0 */15 * * * *",async ()=>{
    await updateRiderCoords();
}));
useEffect(() => {
    job.start();
}, []);
```